# How to find object with Missing label?

Tags: axapta

I have a requirement where I need to create a list of all missing labels in any particular object.

For example.

I want to create a new table with a couple of fields and an overridden method. Now, suppose I am setting up the table property label as "Car details" similarly I am creating new fields and setting their label properties as "Car" and "Model" respectively and overriding validateWrite method with the error "Car-model combination not valid". But, I am not creating a label for any one of them. So now I want to write a job which will show that I need to create three missing labels.

I know Best practice check will give me warnings for the above scenario but I need it as a list as I'll use this list to enhance the Label editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the BP check is the best way or reuse the BP class running the check to push the results as you need.

The advantage to use the standard tool is you can export the result into a file and reopen it later in an output window. You can then double-clic on an item to correct it. Or you can copy/paste the list to Excel to order/filter per BP error and do a follow-up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the AOT using the TreeNode class and select elements where the label property is blank. Then you can send the information out to the infolog or whatever you wish.

There are numerous code examples out there of how to do that, such as [this one looping over forms selecting on the HTMLHelpTopic property.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsiebold/2010/08/13/use-x-to-loop-through-the-aot/)